# Will the privacy sandbox have an impact on xmlhttprequest requests and will there be a problem with authentication?

Tags: cookies, python-requests, xmlhttprequest, sandbox, csrf-token

I want to ask whether the privacy sandbox will have an effect on ajax requests and xmlhttprequest, because I have a site that logs in to Instagram via requests and uses the session key and csrftoken, which it extracts from the cookie field in the request header and does various things such as following others, liking specific posts, etc., because My website is dedicated to increasing followers automatically, so will there be a problem and what are the alternative solutions?

Because, as you can see, cookies are used to fetch the values ​​required for authentication

```
cookie = f"sessionid='{coo.get('sessionid', '')}',ds_user_id='{coo.get('ds_user_id', '')}',csrftoken='{coo.get('csrftoken', '')}'"
```